# How to write a List of string arrays to txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

Is it possible to write a List of string arrays to txt file?

This is my code and I'm not sure how to make the final step. I made a list through which I `foreach` based on the number the user inputs, and it returns all the values correctly, but I can't seem to be able to save all the data to a txt file.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj:");

        int userNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var numberLIst = Enumerable.Range(1,userNumber).ToList();

        string path = @"C:\Users\mcrnic\Desktop\scriptFolder\input.txt";

        List<string[]> listaStringova = new List<string[]>();

        int n = 0;

        foreach (var data in numberLIst)
        {             

            n++;

            #region Varijable
            var textBoxNumberRangeFirst = "tbxNumberRangeFirstInput" + data;
            var textBoxNumberRangeSecond = "tbxNumberRangeSecondInput" + data;
            var textBoxNumberRangeThird = "tbxNumberRangeThirdInput" + data;
            var textBoxHomeNumbersFirst = "tbxRangeOfHomeNumbersFirstInput" + data;
            var textBoxHomeNumbersSecond = "tbxRangeOfHomeNumbersSecondInput" + data;
            var textBoxVPNFirst = "tbxRangeOfShortVPNNumbersFirstInput" + data;
            var textBoxVPNSecond = "tbxRangeOfShortVPNNumbersSecondInput" + data;
            var checkBoxNumberTransfer = "cbxNumberTransfer" + data;
            var checkBoxSecretNumber = "cbxSecretNumber" + data;
            var checkBoxSearchByNumber = "cbxSearchByNumber" + data;
            var checkBoxZ1 = "cbxZ1_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ2 = "cbxZ2_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ3 = "cbxZ3_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ4 = "cbxZ4_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ5 = "cbxZ5_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ6 = "cbxZ6_" + data;
            var checkBoxZ7 = "cbxZ7_" + data;
            #endregion

            string[] htmlLinije = {"<%-- Row" + n + " --%>",
                                "<div class=&row rowFullWidth form-inline pb10& hidden>",
                                "<div class=&col-sm-4&>",
                                "<asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxNumberRangeFirst + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-25 ml10& ReadOnly=&true& />",
                                "<span class=&pr5 pl5&>/</span><asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxNumberRangeSecond +"& class=&form-control textbox-width-25& ReadOnly=&true&/>",
                                "<span class=&pr5 pl5&>-</span><asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxHomeNumbersSecond + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-25& ReadOnly=&true&/>",
                                "</div>",
                                "<div class=&col-sm-2&>",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxNumberTransfer + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pl20 pr15 pt5& Enabled=&false&/>",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxSecretNumber + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pl20 pr15 pt5& Enabled=&false&/>",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxSearchByNumber + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pl20 pr15 pt5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "</div>",
                                "<div class=&col-sm-2&>",
                                "<asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxHomeNumbersFirst + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-40& ReadOnly=&true& /><span class=&pr10 pl10&>-</span>",
                                "<asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxHomeNumbersSecond + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-40& ReadOnly=&true& />",
                                "</div>",
                                "<div class=&col-sm-2&>",
                                "<asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxVPNFirst + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-40& ReadOnly=&true& /><span class=&pr10 pl10&>-</span>",
                                "<asp:TextBox runat=&server& ID=&" + textBoxVPNSecond + "& class=&form-control textbox-width-40& ReadOnly=&true& />",
                                "</div>",
                                "<div class=&col-sm-2&>",
                                "<div class=&pt5&>",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ1 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ2 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ3 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ4 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ5 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ6 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "<asp:CheckBox runat=&server& ID=&" + checkBoxZ7 + "& AutoPostBack=&false& CssClass=&checkbox pr5& Enabled=&false& />",
                                "</div>",
                                "</div>",
                                "</div>",
                                ""
            };

            listaStringova.Add(htmlLinije);                
        }


        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, listaStringova);

    }
```

I get this error when I try to `WriteAllLines`:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to string[]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get this error when i try to WriteAllLines:

Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>' to 'string[]'

Comment: I am sorry that i have to say that, but it is so frustrating to see all these horrible code formatting from the newcomers like you. Please put some effort in  proper formatting the code. This would make us way more likely to help you and understand the code and your problem easier and quicker.

Comment: Like you said mate i'm a newcomer thus i do not yet know how to format code properly, and if you cannot help out please do not post unnecessary comments.

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the problem / issue is.. do a google search on how to access`List<string[]>` values, `List<string>` is all you need to do..

Comment: @MatijaCrnić You are a SO member since 8 months, i joined 4 months ago. Its about how much it means to you and how much **effort** you put into it. On SO is enough information on how to proper format code. You just have to **want** it.

Comment: @L.Guthardt Yet, your edit to his question was not well formatted. What an irony :-). I'm sure we all agree with your comments, but you've got to follow it yourself too ;-). You can check my edit to see a better formatting.

Comment: @RacilHilan I know it wasnt a *good* edit, the only purpose of this edit was to add the provided information from the comments to the question itself. I didnt bother to completely edit the question itself, since i spend the last few days continuously editing questions and trying to improve them. At some point of the day humans are likely to loose their motivation to keep doing what they do. :-)

Comment: @L.Guthardt I was not talking about editing the entire quest, I get what you said, but I was talking specifically about your addition of those last 3 lines. You should've formatted them properly so nobody else needed to do that.

Comment: @RacilHilan Agreed, was a mistake of mine. Will either put effort in it or leave the question as it is, dont want to produce even more content than it already is that has to be edited. As the comment section even expanded so much, i think no one will see it as a harm if i will put this rare SO not intended interpersonal conversation statement here: Was nice talking to you, i appreciate your comments. Have a nice day, kind stranger. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) expects an array of strings as the second parameter. You are sending an array of string arrays, so you need to flatten this list first.

This can be done using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
var stringlist = listaStringova.SelectMany(line => line);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, stringlist);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a list of string arrays to the file. You have to write a list of strings (one string for each line):

`List<string> listStringova = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to WriteAllLines for the List, not the string[]. Per MSDN, the only overload for WriteAllLines takes `IEnumerable<String>`, NOT `IEnumerable<String[]>`. Further, you should make proper use of the `StringBuilder` class, and then do a `WriteAllText`. This would help you tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
List<string[]> listaStringova = new List<string[]>();
```

To:

```
List<string> listaStringova = new List<string>();
```

That's how you declare a list of strings. Then change this:

```
listaStringova.Add(htmlLinije);
```

To:

```
listaStringova.AddRange(htmlLinije);
```

That's how you add all items of your array to your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this one line of code :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, listaStringova.SelectMany(i => i));
```